# How to partially update views in an app widget without rebuilding all the RemoteViews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, remoteview

I'm implementing an app widget and I'd like to be able to change the property of a single view in the widget layout, without rebuilding all the `RemoteViews` from scratch, which involves loading XML etc and which is not necessary in some circumstances.. Is there a way to say "update property X on view identified by a specific ID in the current widget layout"? I've seen that there is a `partiallyUpdateAppWidget` method in the `AppWidgetManager` class but I can't understand nor if it is meant for this purpose neither how it must be used.. Can you help me or point me to a useful link or example?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use `partiallyUpdateAppWidge`t method in the `AppWidgetManager` class.
As an example, if you want to update a text view inside a widget:

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout); 
rv.setTextViewText(R.id.ofTextViewInWidgetLayoutXML, "Hello World");
appWidgetManager.partiallyUpdateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, rv);
```

Ref:
[Just update a widget RemoteViews instead of completly creating a new one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528824/just-update-a-widget-remoteviews-instead-of-completly-creating-a-new-one)