# how to partially Update AppWidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I am writing an AppWidget which has a view(Textview for example) displaying information what the user chooses , I  want my UI-event handler to update ONLY the textview each time UI-Event is triggered , the question is how do I update ONLY the Textview via Remoteviews , is the AppWidgetManager's partiallyUpdateAppWidget method the solution, if true , please show me its usage , thanks in advance

Comment: nice one ,if u find something usefull add it

Answer (score 0):

if you write it to api 11 and above use:

```
 // Get the layout for the App Widget  
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
views.setTextViewText(id,text);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

as shown in this question
[How to partially update views in an app widget without rebuilding all the RemoteViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808331/how-to-partially-update-views-in-an-app-widget-without-rebuilding-all-the-remote)

otherwise rebuild the entire removeviews (basiclly call remoteViews again)